Is using fire as a means of defense or punishment kufr?
It is narrated in https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2013/05/11/haram-to-punish-with-fire/:

Ibn Abbas reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Do not punish with the punishment of Allah Almighty,” meaning fire.

Does this narration imply that the one who uses fire as a means of defense or punishment commits an act of kufr, as he is using an element as a means to attack someone that only Allah may use?

Also see this for using fire.

Not really. Maybe I should elaborate more on my question. In essence, if someone uses fire as a means of killing someone without qisas after they've been captured, can that amount to kufr based off of the saying: “Do not punish with the punishment of Allah Almighty”?

Kufr is disbelief in the essentials of Islam. Sins are not kufr unless they are accompanied by a belief which constitutes kufr, in this case if a person punishes by fire thinking that he is god then that would be kufr.

I see, thank you!
